# jest: test case for returning null. I tried diff solutions but not works for me

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to test `return null;`

I already tried `expect(comp.type()).toEqual(null)` and `expect(comp.get(0)).toBeFalsy()` both not working for me.

**abc.js**

```
render() {
    const { hasError } = this.state;
        if (hasError) {
            return null;
        }
    .....
}
```

**abc.test.js**

```
it('+++ incorporates Search', () => {
        wrapper.setState({ hasError: true });
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
});
```

Console gives me data.

Comment: this is not working. I am not getting wrapper null. I am getting wrapper with data

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what render library you use. If it's enzyme you may:

```
expect(wrapper.getElement()).toBe(null);
```

kudos to https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/52

If you use other library there should be something similar. But you know what? I believe you better no doing such strict check. Returning empty string instead of `null` should look the same in browser. So making such narrowed testing you shoot in your own leg.

Just checking `wrapper.text()` to be empty should good alternative.

PS also consider replacing `wrapper.setState` with some `props` based(pass prop, change prop, call prop by `simulate` etc) communication. Because your code may fail to set `this.state.hasError` in say `componentDidUpdate` but you will never know that since your tests are setting `state` directly.